# Manually reload kde options

Tags: kde-4

If I change some settings in `~/.kde4/share/config/*` is there a command or method for reloading those settings without restarting X or logging-off?

Comment: Create a copy of the file, if you do some bad changes to the original file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what needs to be reloaded, you can also try

killall kded4
kded4

Comment: Why write kded4 twice?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried 'kwin --replace &'?  I've used that when kde gets 'stuck', but it might read the new settings first.

Comment: That reloads the window manager, but the setting I'm changing does not reload. In particular it is touchpadEnabled=bool in the file ktouchpadenablerrc